# Can I write complex SQL in Ontop, Protége that includes JOIN, ST_Equals and ST_StartPoint?

Tags: sql, sparql, postgis, protege

I am defining mappings that are not explicitly avaialable in the database. Rather I am using ST_Equals & ST_StartPoint functions to get the values. When I execute the SQL, I get the correct results*; However when I write SPARQL query, the query keeps running and I dont get any data back.

The SPARQL written is a simple one.

Comment: showing mappings and SPARQL query would be helpful. I'd also suggest to ask on the Ontop mailing list, the devs there help pretty fast

Comment: ok, I guess you also aksed on the Ontop mailing list - but the same holds there, showing mapping and the SPARQL query would be necessary to give further advice

Comment: It worked, but it took a lot of time and I found that ST_Equals is computationally expensive, so I changed it and the performance is much better.